# GCPを使って、サイズの大きなＣＳＶファイルをリクエスト受信する方法は？

Tags: google-app-engine, csv, google-cloud

現在、GAE(standard開発環境)にてサイズの大きなCSVファイルを受信して、解析するウェブアプリケーションの作成を試みております。

公式GCPでは、リクエストのサイズ上限が32MBであることが明記されており、32.8MB以上のCSVファイルがリクエストできないことは実証済であります。

リクエストがGCPの外から送られる場合、ファイル制限をGAE側ではできないため、
何か良い方法がないか模索中です。
・GoogleCloudStorageを使う
→ 読み込みには認証なしでも可能であるが、書き込みには必要である
・GKEを使う
→ GAEに比べて、より細かい制御ができるようだが、そもそもリクエストがGCPのフロントエンドで弾かれているのではないか、と心配している。

何か、打破するためのアドバイスや知見、アイデアを頂けないでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google App Engine Standardにファイルをアップロード, ダウンロードする場合、よくやる手段は以下の2つです。

## Blobstore Serviceを利用する

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/blobstore/
Blobstore Serviceを通じて、ファイルをGoogle Cloud Storage上にアップロード, ダウンロードすることができます。
App EngineでBlobstore用のURLを発行して、クライアントにはそこにアップロードしてもらいます。
アップロードが完了すると、App EngineにCallbackが返ってきます。

## Google Cloud Storage Signed URLを利用する

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls?hl=ja
Signed URLは署名付きのながーいURLを発行し、一定時間そのURLを知っていれば、Cloud Storageにアクセス可能という機能です。
こちらもBlobstoreと同じようにApp EngineからSigned URLを発行して、クライアントにはそこにファイルをアップロードしてもらいます。
ただ、Callback機能はないので、アップロードが完了したのかどうかはApp Engineが見に行く必要があります。

## その他

Google Compute Engine, Google Kubernetes Engineを利用して、自前でWeb Serverを立てても、もちろんファイルアップロード, ダウンロードは可能です。
アップロードされたファイルをメモリに展開したい時やインストール型のミドルウェアで処理したい時などは、これらの手段が検討されます。
ただ、その場合はHTTPSの証明書の設定などは自分でやる必要があります。